# Error elemento O EXPECTING AN ELEMENT

Tags: kotlin

estoy intentando hacer esto con mi codigo pero genera un error. soy principiante en kotlin gracias de antemano. como puedo corregirlo o hacerlo mas factible para pasarle el dato de una variable a la funcion

```
 var dato : Int? 
dato= readLine()?.toInt()
var mes : Int?
mes= $llamadaAtodasLasFunciones(dato)  //error en esta linea 

fun apuntarMese(apuntar : Int) {
    when(apuntar) {
    1,2,3,4 -> println("corresponde al primer cuatrimestre")  
    5,6,7,8 -> println("corresponde al segundo cuatrimestre")
    9,10,11,12 -> println("corresponde al tercer cuatrimestre")
    else -> { println("No esta dentro de los meses del año")
    }
}
}

fun mesesRango(mes: Int) {
when(mes) {
    in 1..6 ->println("Primer semestres del año")
    in 7..12 ->println("Segundo  semestres del año") 
    !in 1..12 ->println("No corresponde a los meses que necesita") 
    }
}
fun llamadaAtodasLasFunciones(mes: Int) {
    //meses2021(mes)
    apuntarMese(mes)
    mesesRango(mes)
    }
```

Comment: no se entiende lo que intentas hacer. Qué quieres almacenar en la variable mes?. El error es que sobra el signo `$` delante de tu función. Pero hay otro error y es tratar de asignarle a una variable de tipo `Int?` el resultado de `llamadaAtodasLasFunciones`

Comment: lo que quiero es pasarle el valor de la variable a la función  ya le quite el $ y sigue igual me da error

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos errores en estas líneas

```
var mes : Int?
mes= $llamadaAtodasLasFunciones(dato)
```

1. sobra este signo `$`
2. el resultado de la función `llamadaAtodasLasFunciones` no se puede asignar a una variable de tipo `Int?`

Si lo que quieres es pasarle el valor de la variable `dato`, hazlo directamente. No necesitas crear otra variable

```
val dato = readLine()!!.toInt()
llamadaAtodasLasFunciones(dato)
```

Como eres principiante tal vez necesites que explique ese código

1. Puedes hacer la declaración de la variable y la asignación en la misma línea
2. No necesitas especificar el tipo de dato porque el compilador puede inferirlo
3. Si no necesitas cambiar el valor de la variable, deberías declararla usando la palabra `val` en vez de `var`. Esto es lo que otros lenguajes llaman constante pero en kotlin se llama variable de sólo lectura
4. El operador `!!` le dice al compilador que ese valor no puede ser nulo. Como resultado tu variable es de tipo `Int` en vez de `Int?`
5. Ahora que el tipo de tu variable coincide con el tipo del parámetro de la función, puedes pasarla como argumento